# Get elements by position from one data frame to another

Tags: r

Let's say we have two data frames:

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = letters[1:3], B = letters[4:6], C = letters[7:9], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  A B C
1 a d g
2 b e h
3 c f i

df2 <- data.frame(V1 = 1:3, V2 = 4:6, V3 = 7:9)
  V1 V2 V3
1  1  4  7
2  2  5  8
3  3  6  9
```

I need to build a function that takes as input a single value or a vector containing elements from one of the data frames and returns the elements from the other data frame according to their positional indexes.

The function should work like this:

```
> matchdf(values = c("a", "e", "i"), dfin = df1, dfout = df2)
[1] 1 5 9

> matchdf(values = c(1, 5, 9), dfin = df2, dfout = df1)
[1] "a" "e" "i"

> matchdf(values = c(1, 1, 1), dfin = df2, dfout = df1)
[1] "a" "a" "a"
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
requiere(dplyr)
toVec   <- function(df) df %>% as.matrix %>% as.vector
matchdf <- function(values, dfin, dfout) toVec(dfout)[toVec(dfin) %in% values]

# But sometimes the output values aren't in correct order:
> matchdf(c("c", "i", "h"), dt1, dt2)
[1] 3 8 9
# should output 3 9 8

> matchdf(values = c("a", "a", "a"), dfin = dt1, dfout = dt2)
[1] 1
# Should output 1 1 1
```

Feel free to use `data.table` or/and `dplyr` if it eases the task. I would prefer a solution without for loops.

**Assumptions**:

- elements from df1 are different from df2
- dim(df1) = dim(df2)

Comment: In my opinion you on the right track. And rather then converting your dataframes to vectors, work with vectors in the first place. Also, I would just do something like `values = c("a", "e", "i") ; unlist(df2)[match(values, unlist(df1))]` instead of using dplyr and creating two functions.

Comment: @DavidArenburg it works, you should post your answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
matchdf <- function(values, dfin, dfout){
        unlist(sapply(values, 
                      function(val) dfout[dfin == val], 
                      USE.NAMES = F)
               )
}

matchdf(c("c", "i", "h"), df1, df2)
#should output 3 9 8
[1] 3 9 8
matchdf(values = c("a", "a", "a"), dfin = df1, dfout = df2)
#should output 1 1 1
[1] 1 1 1
matchdf(values = c("X", "Y", "a"), dfin = df1, dfout = df2)
#should output vector, not list
[1] 1
```

Comment: This is bad answer both because this is just a code-dump without any explanations (which is useless for future readers) and because it teaches users to run loops over fully vectorized operations.